# getting error of Unable to add listener of type while deploying in glassfish5.0.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-8, glassfish

**Glassfish log**

```
[#|2019-10-22T19:16:12.273+0530|SEVERE|glassfish 5.0|javax.enterprise.web.core|_ThreadID=87 _ThreadName=pool-8-thread-1;_TimeMillis=1571751972273;_LevelValue=1000;_MessageID=AS-WEB-CORE 00108;|
    ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to add listener of type: com.ipaccess.nos.service.web.NosContextLoaderListener, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5537)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.deploy(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.execute(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.AbstractOSGiDeployer.deploy(AbstractOSGiDeployer.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiContainer.deploy(OSGiContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.deploy(JavaEEExtender.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.access$200(JavaEEExtender.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to add listener of type: com.ipaccess.nos.service.web.NosContextLoaderListener, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2867)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:2073)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5534)
    ... 24 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to add listener of type: com.ipaccess.nos.service.web.NosContextLoaderListener, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2982)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:5057)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1637)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2865)
    ... 31 more
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: NOS TR69 AP Service
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.ipaccess.nos.service.tr69ap
Bundle-Version: 3.0.0
Bundle-Vendor: ip.access
Export-Package: com.ipaccess.nos.service.tr69ap.southbound.api
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: com.ipaccess.nos.business.cm.api,
javax.servlet,
javax.servlet.http,
org.osgi.framework;version="1.5.0",
org.slf4j,
org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support;version="1.2.1",
org.springframework.remoting.rmi,
org.springframework.util;version="3.0.5.RELEASE",
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation;version="3.0.5.RELEASE",
org.springframework.web.context;version="3.0.5.RELEASE",
org.springframework.web.context.support;version="3.0.5.RELEASE",
org.springframework.web.servlet;version="3.0.5.RELEASE",
org.aspectj.lang,
org.aspectj.lang.annotation,
org.aspectj.lang.reflect,
org.aspectj.runtime.internal,
org.aspectj.runtime.reflect,
org.aopalliance.aop,
org.aopalliance.intercept,
com.ipaccess.nos.service.web
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/com.ipaccess.nos.Tr69Stack.jar,
WEB-INF/classes,.
Require-Bundle: org.springframework.beans;bundle-version="3.0.5",
org.springframework.core;bundle-version="3.0.5",
org.springframework.context,
org.springframework.osgi.web;bundle-version="1.2.1";bundle-version:=optional,
org.springframework.osgi.core;bundle-version="1.2.1",
org.springframework.osgi.extender;bundle-version="1.2.1",
org.springframework.osgi.io;bundle-version="1.2.1",
com.ipaccess.nos.business,
com.springsource.org.aopalliance;bundle-version="1.0.0",
org.springframework.aop;bundle-version="3.0.5",
org.springframework.osgi.extender,
com.springsource.javax.servlet;bundle-version="2.5.0"
Web-ContextPath: /
Spring-Context: *;timeout:=600
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="false" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<listener>
  <listener-class>com.ipaccess.nos.service.web.NosContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
<param-name>debug</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>nos-tr069</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.ipaccess.nos.service.tr69ap.southbound.AcsController</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>nos-tr069</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/acs</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
  <filter-name>lockStatusFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.ipaccess.nos.service.web.HttpAdminLockStateFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>lockStatusFilter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>nos-tr069</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

NosContextLoaderListener (it present in other jar). issue explanation.
    Details are given below

We are using OSGi Felix in Glassfish 5.0.1. We are facing this issue while upgrading our 
    project from Java 6 to Java 8 (Oracle JDK version 1.8.0_221), from Glassfish 3.1.1 to Glassfish
    5.0.1 and OSGi Equinox to OSGi Felix.

Comment: we are using osgi felix in glassfish 5.0.1. We are facing this issue while upgrading our 
project from java6 to java8 (oracle jdk version -1.8.0_221) , from glassfish 3.1.1 to glassfish
5.0.1 and osgi equinox to osgi felix.

Comment: Did you try to actually implement one of the listed interfaces?? ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener

Comment: Yes I have extended ContextLoaderListener (in my class- NosContextLoaderListener). and This ContextLoaderListener which is belong to org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener (spring jar). ContextLoaderListener already implemented ServletContextListener. The same thing is already working with java6 with glassfish 3.1.1.  We are trying to upgrade to java8 with glassfish5.0.1 so we are facing this issue.

Comment: Can you share the code of the NosContextLoaderListener class?

Comment: import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;

public class NosContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

      //Some codes
   }

   protected Class<?> determineContextClass(ServletContext servletContext) {
      return OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext.class ;
   }
}

Comment: ContextLoaderListener internally implemented ServletContextListener.